# Perl regex that can match both positive and negative values

Tags: regex, perl

I have a list of data which  I want to match:

```
0:1
0:3
0:-1
0:2
0:-4
```

What's the regex I can use to match all of them:

I tried this but won't work:

```
$line =~ /0:(\w+)/
```

It only match the positives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\w` is for word symbols: letters, digits and underscore. That means your regexp besides `0:34` will match smth like `0:hello`, but won't match minus symbol.

If you need only digits then `/0:-?\d+/` should work. And if you need to match whole string (to filter out strings like `a0:-3b` you can use `/^0:-?\d+$/`.

Answer (score 1):

how about `$line =~ /0:[-]?[0-9]`

Comment: The `[]` around the `-` is useless, unless you have a `+` there as well